# A mixed Vandermonde-Wronskian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, galois-theory, differential-operators

I am trying to prove that a matrix of the following form is generically nonsingular:

$A= \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1 \\ 
 f_1 & f_2 & f_3 &f_4  \\ 
 (f_1 -\frac{d}{dt}).f_1& (f_2 -\frac{d}{dt}).f_2 & (f_3 -\frac{d}{dt}).f_3 &(f_4 -\frac{d}{dt}).f_4 \\ 
 (f_1 -\frac{d}{dt})^2 .f_1& (f_2 -\frac{d}{dt})^2 .f_2 & (f_3 -\frac{d}{dt})^2.f_3 &(f_4 -\frac{d}{dt})^2 .f_4 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

where  $f_1 , ... , f_m $  are meromorphic or analytic functions of the undetermined variables $(x_1 , ... x_n)$. ( each $(f_i -d/dt)$ is a operator that acts from left) 
is there any known results on the nonsingularity of matrices of this form?
note that one can write the determinant of the matrix $A$ as sum of a Vandermonde and a Wronskian determinant.

Could we prove that this sum is generically nonzero?